# How to connect facebook with sharekit?

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios, sharekit

I am a new bie and first time using Facebook in the application.

For this I am using sharekit..

And it works fine in the example...

Now I have some specific requirement...

it is like i want to make a button..whenever i click this button...it should be go to facebook

can anyone tell me what should i do here and another thing ..is it good to use sharekit for all this stuff?? or should I use any other api??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did it!!!

This helped me a lot

[iPhone/iOS - How to use "ShareKit" to post only to Facebook or only to Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432297/iphone-how-to-use-sharekit-only-to-post-to-facebook-or-only-to-twitter)

Answer (score 0):

This days their is another great option: 
UIActivityViewController.
[example of use](http://www.codingexplorer.com/sharing-swift-app-uiactivityviewcontroller)