# Does ShareKit work with iPhone OS 3.0?

Tags: ios, sharekit

If I simply set the deployment target to OS 3.0 will Sharekit still work on devices? It seems working fine in emulater but I don't have a OS 3.0 device to test it further.

Comment: The percentage of devices running less than 3.1 is probably less than 0.1%...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to find this explicitly stated anywhere in ShareKits docs, after downloading ShareKit and opening the project it appears to have it's deployment target set to iOS 3.2.

Although this isn't exactly a "for sure" indicator that ShareKit doesn't work below 3.2, it seems to suggest that you MAY indeed run into compatibility issues on iOS 3.0.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. But i couldn't get sharekit work at all. I followed this guide,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432297/iphone-how-to-use-sharekit-only-to-post-to-facebook-or-only-to-twitter

But sharekit didn't work for me. Not even their sample app seems to be working. When I try Twitter option it give an error saying couldn't communicate with twitter. Anyone else having this issue?